# overriding virtual function to non-virtual function is OK?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

```
class Base
{
    virtual void foo();
}


class Derived : public Base
{
    void foo();
}
```

It it OK?
Or it can make some problems?
I think it insist "DO NOT INHERIT FROM DERIVED".

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're talking about (C++ I guess).

Comment: Yes please tag as in C# it will give you following warning. "hides inherited member Base.foo(). To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword." You can read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: It's not even possible. The function remains virtual, even if you don't say so.

Answer (score 2):

Once you marked the `foo()` function in Base class as `virtual` it is implicitly `virtual` in Derived class, even if you don't mention the keyword `virtual` in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

`virtual`ness is inherited. Even if you do not declare an overridden method `virtual`, it will be virtual.

Hence, if you access an object of `Derived` using `Base` pointer or reference, it will call `foo` of `Derived`.

Answer (score 0):

virtual functions are inherited automatically. So even if you don't declare it as virtual, it is virtual actually.

The reason for you to explicitly declare it as virtual is for better clarification so that anyone reading this code can instantly understand that it is a virtual functions, without having to check the base class declarations.

Comment: Marking it virtual guarantees that it's virtual, even if the base class has a member function with the same signature that is **not** virtual. There's no shortcut that lets you write correct code without understanding what you're doing. (Okay, the new `override` keyword might make life easier for lazy programmers...)